# AWS Cognito OAuth2 with PCKE "Invalid Request" Code Challenge

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito

I have been trying to add the `state` and `code_challenge` to our flow but for some reason, I continue to get `invalid_request` responses from Amazon.

I followed this [Auth0 tutorial](https://auth0.com/docs/flows/add-login-using-the-authorization-code-flow-with-pkce) to a tee.

```js
  /**
   * Converts buffer to Base64 URL encoded string
   *
   * @param {Buffer} buf The buffer to convert
   * @returns {string}
   */
  private base64URLEncode(str: any): string {
    return str.toString('base64').replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/\//g, '_').replace(/=/g, '');
  }

  /**
   * Generates a new code challenge
   *
   * @returns {string} The code challange string
   */
  private generateCodeChallenge(): string {
    if (!this._verifier) this._verifier = this.base64URLEncode(crypto.randomBytes(32));

    return this.base64URLEncode(crypto.createHash('sha256').update(this._verifier).digest());
  }

  /**
   * Generates the Authorization URL
   */
  public generateAuthUrl(): string {
    if (!this.config.clientId) throw new Error('Client ID is missing from configuration.');
    if (!this.config.redirectUrl) throw new Error('Redirect URI is missing from configuration.');

    if (!this._state) this._state = this.base64URLEncode(crypto.randomBytes(28));

    return `${this.config.protocol}://signin.${
      this.config.host
    }/login?response_type=code&client_id=${this.config.clientId}&redirect_uri=${
      this.config.redirectUrl
    }&scope=${this._scope.join('%20')}&state=${
      this._state
    }&code_challenge_method=S256&code_challenge=${this.generateCodeChallenge()}`;
  }

  /**
   * Verifies that the state matches
   *
   * @returns {boolean}
   */
  public verifyState(state: string): boolean {
    return this._state === state;
  }

  /**
   * Retrieves a new OAuth Authorization Grant token
   */
  public async getToken(code: string): Promise<UserAccessToken> {
    if (!this.config.clientId) throw new Error('Client ID is missing from configuration.');
    if (!this.config.redirectUrl) throw new Error('Redirect URI is missing from configuration.');

    try {
      const token = (await this.req.postform(
        `/oauth2/token`,
        {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Cache-Control': 'no-store',
          },
        },
        {
          grant_type: 'authorization_code',
          code,
          client_id: this.config.clientId,
          code_verifier: this._verifier,
          redirect_uri: this.config.redirectUrl,
        }
      )) as UserAccessToken;

      this._userAccessToken = token;

      return token;
    } catch (err) {
      throw err;
    }
  }
```

Everything is working well up until exchanging a code for a token. We redirect to our hosted UI and successfully get a code back. When we exchange that for a token, no matter what I have tried, we get an `invalid_request` response. If I remove the code challenge, everything works as expected so I am pretty confident that it's what is causing the issue.

[image: Hosted UI]

[image: Redirect Back to Admin]

[image: Attempt to get Access Token]

### Update 1

This function is called in our React app inside of a `useEffect` hook like so:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const authUrl = sdk.auth.generateAuthUrl();
    console.log(authUrl);
    if (!code) window.location.assign(authUrl);
    console.log(`New Auth URL: ${authUrl}`);
    sdk.auth
      .getToken(code as string)
      .then((token) => {
        localStorage.setItem('sdk_access_token', JSON.stringify(token));
        sdk.organizations.getUser().then((user) => {
          setUser({ ...user });
          history.push('/');
        });
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }, []);
```

Both `console.log` statements show the same URL:
[image: Console Screenshot]

But on the Network debugging tab, the request URL is different:
[image: Network Screenshot]

How is that possible? Does `window.location.href` somehow encode the URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code and messages look fine as far as I can see. If you have an App Client Secret configured in Cognito that would explain the problem (Cognito error responses are not the best).

Maybe try these hard coded values from a working Cognito sample of mine - or run the values you are calculating through [this tool](https://tonyxu-io.github.io/pkce-generator/). This will enable you to know whether the problem is with the PKCE values:

- challenge: tQV5Ny5h0r5pwqpDr0OGnQWgfU4DTTniuu99HZGOOE0
- verifier: 4ffc114e504047deb57f3e8dfeeda70d93bbfb6d8f0444c9b9b147f3872dbde24f58cbe3047d49ce9b5194fe80e0905a

There are plenty of libraries with some [working PKCE code](https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-JS/blob/master/src/authorization_request.ts#L78) though I expect the Auth0 code is fine ...

Comment: So weird. If I hardcode the values, it works. Using the tool you suggested, my verifier and code challenge match what they should be. However, if I generate the values... it fails. Going to try to debug a little further.

Comment: Added some additional findings. I think it might be the browser re-encoding the code challenge somehow.

Comment: Try using encodeUriComponent for all query parameters in the authorization redirect and all form parameters in the post. Maybe compare to the code to a working library that uses PKCE such as [oidc-client](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js/blob/dev/src/JsonService.js).

Comment: Your original comment was right: "Your code and messages look fine as far as I can see". The problem was with React re-loading state. We generated the challenge/verifier, then redirected the user to AWS. When they were redirected back, the class was re-initialized and the verifier was `undefined`. For some reason though the network tab still showed it as being sent. When we hard-coded the variables, they were just re-initialized to the same thing which threw me for the loop.